# What is the "set HTML" counterpart to appendTo and prependTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

From official jQuery on clone:

```
$( ".hello" ).clone().appendTo( ".goodbye" )
```

I have seen appendTo and prependTo to copy the DOM events. What is the counterpart function to set the HTML of a div to that "clone"? What methods does a "clone" support?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here because you seem to have answered what you have asked with your code example.

Comment: I cannot understand your question precisely.. can you please rephrase it to make a clear question.?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean but take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/3PWz5/ and see if it is what you are asking. Basically `$( ".hello" ).clone().appendTo( ".goodbye" ).find('element')`

Comment: Can you give an example of `appendTo` copying events? In my understanding `clone` is the way to go when copying events of one element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clone` returns a jQuery object, so it supports all the methods that a jQuery object usually supports.

To replace an element's content, you would typically `empty` it and then `append` the new content.

```
$('.goodbye').empty().append(
    $('.hello').clone()
);
```